# Смена I/O scheduler в Linux

Tags: linux, многопоточность, debian, scheduler

Имеет ли смысл менять планировщик на сервере видеостриминга(flussonic) для улучшения производительности? В данном случае для снижения нагрузки на CPU.
[image: Текущая нагрузка на сервер]

[image: Список доступных планировщиков]

Если нет, то поможет ли апгрейд системы и ядра(Последовательно перейти с Ubuntu 16.04.4 на 20.04 и применить mq-deadline, загрузить пропатченное ядро).

Comment: Если процессор занят работой по транскодированию видео, то изменение параметров ввода-вывода не повлияет на процессор вообще никак

Comment: @andreymal кроме высокой нагрузки на процессор, в логах пишет что иногда планировщик нагружен >90%, собственно поэтому я и задумался.

Comment: открой обычный топ и посмотри как изменяется iowait при смене планировщика. в htop не показывает что там в красной полоске

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент рекомендуют использовать mq-deadline или bfq.

Пруф: https://habr.com/ru/post/337102/

Я использую bfq...

Как включить:

BFQ - это планировщик blk-mq (механизм очередей блоков многократного ввода-вывода), поэтому вам нужно включить blk-mq во время загрузки, а именно отредактировать файл `/etc/ default/grub` и добавить `scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1` в  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. Затем : `sudo modprobe bfq`.

После этого: `sudo update-grub`

Важно отметить, что включение blk_mq делает невозможным использование планировщиков не blk_mq, поэтому вы потеряете noop cfq и т.д. Вместо этого можно использовать правила udev с дополнительным преимуществом более детального управления:

Создайте, `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-scheduler.rules` если он не существует, и добавьте:

`ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ATTR{queue/scheduler}="bfq"`

Сохраните его, перезагрузите и запустите udev rules:

`sudo udevadm control --reload`
`sudo udevadm trigger`

Для mq-deadline:https://blog.programs74.ru/how-to-enable-mq-deadline-or-bfq-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.